# Spring-boot 2.0.0 M1 - Actuator not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring-boot project that uses spring-boot actuator to provide application statistics and metrics.

The actuator functionality is being provided by adding "spring-boot-starter-actuator" to the project.

At this point, security is disable, so the project does not import spring-security.

Using spring-boot 1.5.x, all actuator Endpoints (automatic provided, as the /info, as well as my specific defined endpoints), are working correctly.

After updating to Spring-boot 2.0.0 M1, the actuator endpoints are no longer exposed. Invoking the /info endpoint returns the following error:

```
{"timestamp":1496948526890,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No 
message available","path":"/info"}
```

A note regarding Tomcat: i'm redefining the *tomcat.version* property, in order to use version 9.

- When using spring-boot 1.5.x, tomcat.version=9.0.0.M9
- When using spring-boot 2.0.0.M1, tomcat.version=9.0.0.M21

Comment: Does this work when not overriding the Tomcat version? I'm not sure this version is officially supported (yet) by Spring Boot.

Comment: When removing the override, spring-boot uses Tomcat version 8.5.15.
Unfortunately, i got the same error.

I've changed log levels to TRACE, could you please have a look to the logs, to see if you can spot anything?
Please download the log here: https://meocloud.pt/link/4d4c29c6-dc77-4b64-9ef4-fb14038836a7/log.log/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It look's like the endpoint is no longer mapped to /info

`2017-06-08 13:11:57.817 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/application/info || /application/info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()`

and according to the 2.0.0/SNAPSHOT documentation this is expected.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints

Try `/application/info`

Comment: Perfect, it worked correctly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: There is also [a section in the release notes about this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#actuator-default-mapping) now.

Comment: Stephane, thank you for the link. I actually read that page, but i have to admit i missed the actuator part. I saw that i could use the management.context-path attribute in order to override the default setting.

Answer (score 7):

And it's moved again. Right now, the URL are living under `/actuator`, for example: `/actuator/health`.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints

Answer (score 3):

try this

`management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
      base-path: /actuator`

Answer (score 2):

Even you could define a specific path using the management attribute:

> management.context-path =

If you set an empty space, you can reach **"/info"**, as you want.